# POI integration with selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I just want to use *POI integration* with **selenium webdriver**. Previously I used **excel 2003 & Jxl**. I want to use **Excel 2013 & POI** , Is that possible? 
2. How to write code for reading more than 10 columns and using it along with fields.In my case for eg: for a login page , the username field has to take values from the excel in each iteration by reading the excel

If yes, please help me by providing the information.

Comment: Yes you can. Simply download POI jars , add it to your project and use...

Comment: @Helping Hands , Please send me the code

Comment: Everything you will get : http://www.toolsqa.com/

Comment: And another question is can I use excel 2013?

Comment: try it..Might be you can...

Comment: Did you look at the POI site and read the docs?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment , download poi jar from [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org)

> For reading from Excel file include,

- ooxml-schemas-*.jar
- poi-excelant-*.jar
- poi-ooxml-*.jar
- xmlbeans-*.jar
- poi-*.jar

> If it is maven project,
>   include below dependancy in pom.xml. Make sure you use same versions for poi & poi-ooxml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>*</version>

</dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>*</version>

</dependency>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apache POI 3.7 is ancient! Why are you suggesting such an old version?

Comment: Now answer is not version specific.

Comment: All the blogs telling about reading values from Excel . In my case, for example in login for username field , I want to pass the first row value from the excel. How can I do it?

Comment: I mean in case if I have more than 10 colums

Comment: I can suggest you [This](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/) . This will give the enough idea for reading from multiple rows and column of excel file. Also, if it not helps you, please be more specific on your query :)

Comment: @ Mk08 please suggest some other, it's not sufficient :)

Comment: Your question was for POI integration with Selenium webdriver. I guess people have managed to answer that in comments/ as answer. Now if you are facing problem in  reading from multiple column data from Excel using POI, becomes another question. Kindly edit your question with more details OR go through Apache POI docs.